# Eagerly load a collection

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Please see the code below:

```
public Person GetById(Guid id)
        {
            return Session.Get<Person>(id);
        }
```

How can I return a Person that has the Person.Sports collection eagerly loaded?

I have tried using QueryOver and Fetch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify in your mapping that the collection should not be lazy loaded, but then, that collection will be retrieved for every query where you want to load a Person.

I'm sure you can do it with QueryOver, but I haven't used that very much yet.
You can also specify the fetch-mode when using the ICriteria approach:

```
var crit = session.CreateCriteria<Person>();
crit.SetFetchMode("Sports", FetchMode.Eager);
crit.Add(Restrictions.Eq("PersonId", id);
```

Since I wanted to know how to do it using QueryOver as well, I've been googling a bit and I came across [this](http://puredotnetcoder.blogspot.be/2011/09/queryover-eager-loading-parent-and.html).
Have you tried to fetch the entities like this:

```
var query = session.QueryOver<Person>()
                   .Fetch( p => p.Sports).Eager
                   .Left.JoinAlias( p => p.Sports, () => s)
             ...
```